# past simple or past perfect why

Tags: grammar, past-perfect, perfect-aspect, past-simple

Please take a look at the sleeve notes of the revolving paint dreams lp "off to heaven"creation lp a great record by the way.

> The last story I heard that Alan Mc Gee (boss label) had tried to organise a come back concert. After hearing about the plans, however, the band had gone to the studio and burned all the tapes they had ever recorded, then demolished everything in the studio. By the time Mc Gee got there, the studio was a smouldering ruin. After that .....silence
>
> Silence, that is until late last year.

Are "burned" and "demolished" past perfect or are they past simple? Note "had" is not written, but I think it might be left out to avoid repetition.

So if they are past perfect: is it because the destruction happened before McGee arrived (the time reference)?

And if they are not past perfect but past simple, I dont see the necessity of the first past perfect "had gone over."

Is it be possible to write

> the band went to the studio, burned all the tapes they had ever recorded and then demolished everything in the studio.

So, again, if it is past perfect to emphasize their intention to destroy what they did. Or maybe is it because the time reference is "burned." As the arrival in the studio was before the destruction I would understand the use of past perfect "had gone over."

Comment: Are you sure you typed in the material from the sleeve notes exactly as it is, including all the commas, spaces,   and capital words, and that you double-checked it? Because *McGee* usually doesn't have a space in it. And there may or may not be a missing comma in the notes. Also, double-check your first sentence for these same issues.

Comment: Yes you are right, but if I  made a mistake that is because my question is on tenses not on spelling McGee or missing commas. As far as the tenses are concerned , I did not make any errors

Comment: So do you want sloppy or careful answers?

Comment: So careful answers of course. Is it not possible to answer to my question without spelling McGee correctly ? So you think I should write "the band went to the studio and burned all the tapes they had ever recorded and then demolished everything in the studio.This is what you mean in your last sentence? –

Comment: I mean that I already took 5-10 minutes to edit your post to make it *clearer*, so that people can provide better answers. And that I was **asking for your help**, regarding the sleeve notes and your first sentence. So, if you are not willing to put in a few minutes to correct a few known errors, why should anyone care to give you a carefully worded answer?

Comment: @δοῦλος I think it came out a little too strong, though your point is clear and valid. To the OP, it might be true that your spellings may have nothing to do with the grammar, but then again it might as well be. Frankly, the first time I saw your question (there was still no comment), I wondered if it might be possible that you dropped a *had* somewhere, and *Mc Gee* should've been *McGee*, or maybe *come back* should've been *comeback*, why there are many dots in the ellipses? (it should be 3), how they wrote *silence*, and so on. And I can't crosscheck the sleeve notes.

Comment: No I have just double checked and I have not forgotten any "had" . Anyway it is true that I have changed the first sentence , here is the original :" The last story I heard was that label boss Alan McGee had tried to organise a come-back concert, in a last deseperate attempt at giving the bandback some confidence". The last sentence is   :"Silence, that is, until late last year when two seperate reports reached me about the same time."

Comment: @user5577 this is one reason I asked you to check the sleeve notes, because standard usage would be to include **was**. So, since the absence of *was* seemed irregular, I wondered if anything else had been omitted. Also, I have the same questions regarding "come back" and the number of periods in the ellipsis. And since you are **quoting** material, it's necessary to reproduce (write) the material exactly right, not just some of it right.

Comment: In addition, now that you have double-checked the sleeve notes and found you made some errors, you should edit your original question and correct the quotation. That is, the corrections should not appear in a comment (only) but be included in your question post.

Comment: No nothing has been omitted now come-back is written like that and there are six dots before silence So you want the question to be rewrite will do it

Answer (score 1):

> No sooner had I sat down and unwrapped my sandwich, when three
>   squirrels arrived on the scene, hoping for handouts.

One can understand this to mean "had sat down...(had) unwrapped".

So I'd say the verbs in question (burned, demolished) are understood to be in the past-perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, as written, it's ambiguous. The conjunctions `and` and `then` can be understood to each *either* work on the phrase `had gone to the studio`, or simply `gone to the studio`, which changes whether the verbs are attached to `had`. However, typically in English, the simple and perfect past tenses aren't mixed like this, so the author probably intended for "burned" and "demolished" to be in the perfect as well.

To answer your other question, the sentence `the band went to the studio, burned all the tapes they had ever recorded and then demolished everything in the studio.` is perfectly valid sentence--but that's not what was written!