# Past simple or past perfect the reason why

Tags: grammar

up vote
0
down vote
favorite
Please take a look at the sleeve notes of the revolving paint dreams lp "off to heaven"creation lp a great record by the way.

" The last story I heard was that label boss Alan McGee had tried to organise a come-back concert, in a last desperate attempt at giving the band back some confidence. After hearing about the plans, however, the band had gone to the studio and burned all the tapes they had ever recorded, then demolished everything in the studio. By the time McGee got there, the studio was a smouldering ruin. After that ...silence

"Silence, that is, until late last year when two seperate reports reached me about the same time.

Are "burned" and "demolished" past perfect or are they past simple? Note "had" is not written, but I think it might be left out to avoid repetition.

So if they are past perfect: is it because the destruction happened before McGee arrived (the time reference)?

And if they are not past perfect but past simple, I dont see the necessity of the first past perfect "had gone over."

Is it be possible to write

the band went to the studio, burned all the tapes they had ever recorded and then demolished everything in the studio. So, again, if it is past perfect to emphasize their intention to destroy what they did. Or may be is it because the time reference is "burned." As the arrival in the studio was before the destruction I would understand the use of past perfect "had gone over."

Comment: Literal copy/paste of [past simple or past perfect why](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53307/past-simple-or-past-perfect-why).

Comment: no not literal, I was told to correct the mistakes .I did it . Now I would like to have an answer

Comment: Glad you fixed the errors. The proper protocol is to go back to the original question and hit the "edit" button; then make the changes *there*, rather than create a new (duplicate) question. If you're having trouble editing the original question, check out the [help] for some tips.